# running .net utility from command line

Tags: .net, command-line

I have no experience running programs from the command line, and I wish to run mscordmp from the command line which is a VS utility.

The documentation shows as such:
    mscordmp [options] /pid processID /out outputFile

but when I run from command line it says not recognised.  Do i need to ensure a specific prompt?

Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you typing at the command prompt?

Comment: It was at the c:/ prompt and it was mscordmp /pid 4352/ out myDump   and I get unrecognised error.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an old tool back from the .NET 1.x days and is no longer distributed.  Google "clrdump" for an equivalent freeware tool, take the first hit.

Comment: It doesn't have a dependency on .NET, creating minidumps takes unmanaged code.  Btw, you can make them too with Task Manager in Vista and Win7.  Processes tab, right-click the process.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" under the Visual Studio Tools folder (which is under the Microsoft Visual Studio folder) on your start menu.  This sets up all the proper environment variables and path settings that should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder it's in is not in your system's PATH variable, you will have to `cd` into that directory before typing in the code you posted above.

Example (assuming it's at C:\Program Files\Tools):

1) Go to Start -> Run (or hit windows key + R)
2) Type in: cd "C:\Program Files\Tools\"
3) Be sure to add the quotes because program files has a space in it.
4) Now run your command: mscordmp [options] /pid processID /out outputFile